# Get total page load time

Tags: asp.net, performance, web-applications, time

Is there any tool to calculate the total load time for a page which include the ajax postbacks also ?
Whenever i click on any button the timer starts till the time when the page render is done completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP Watch did the thing for me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [**Navigation Timing**](http://www.thoughtresults.com/navigation-timing)